# How to convert a numpy.ndarray object into a date object

Tags: date, numpy

I have a numpy.ndarray object

```
array([[ 2016., 1., 1.],
       [ 2016., 12., 31.]])
```

Could anyone please tell me how to convert it into a date object like

```
date([2016-01-01],
     [2016-12-31])
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see if this is the type of conversion you're looking for: from numpy ndarray to datetime, to string, or to numpy datetime:

```
import datetime as dt
import numpy as np

x = np.array([[ 2016., 1., 1.], [ 2016., 12., 31.]])

string = [dt.datetime(*el).strftime('%Y-%m-%d') for el in x.astype(int)]
string
['2016-01-01', '2016-12-31']

datetime = np.array(datetime, dtype='datetime64[D]')
datetime
array(['2016-01-01', '2016-12-31'], dtype='datetime64[D]')
```